# build haml to html with sublime

Tags: sublimetext2, haml

I want to build the haml in the sublime text 2 without switch to the iterm. So I build a simple plugin for the sublime, just like this.

```
import os
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class HamlToHtmlCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self,edit):
        source = self.view.file_name()
        filefullname = source.split('/')[-1]
        filename = filefullname.split('.')[0]
        target = "/".join(source.split('/')[0:-1])
        com = "haml " + source + " > " + target + "/" + filename +'.html'
        os.system(com)


    def is_enabled(self):
        return True
```

But the problem is that, when i build in the sublime, the target html file is empty.
for example, the "com" is "haml /Users/latpaw/login_register/login.haml    /Users/latpaw/login_register/login.html". But if do the os.system(com) in the python cli, it is right.
So what really happens here

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I really don't know Haml, so at first I just tried to fix your code. But I think you can build Haml directly from ST, by going to `Tools→Build` (<kbd>⌥B</kbd>). Or create a new build system `Tools→Build Systems→New build system`. Apparently you have the following variables that you could use:

- $file   The full path to the current file, e. g., C:\Files\Chapter1.txt.
- $file_path  The directory of the current file, e. g., C:\Files.
- $file_name  The name portion of the current file, e. g., Chapter1.txt.
- $file_extension The extension portion of the current file, e. g., txt.
- $file_base_name The name only portion of the current file, e. g., Document.
- $packages   The full path to the Packages folder.
- $project    The full path to the current project file.
- $project_path   The directory of the current project file.
- $project_name   The name portion of the current project file.
- $project_extension  The extension portion of the current project file.
- $project_base_name  The name only portion of the current project file.

---

Apparently you have an issue with path escaping. You must have, like me when I tried, a space somewhere in the path of your file. Or you probably know that commands like `cat ~/Sublime Text/test` do not work well. You can either:

- `cat ~/Sublime\ Text/test`
- `cat ~/'Sublime Text/test'`

I would advise the later and do this:

```
com = "haml '" + source + "' > '" + target + "/" + filename +"'.html"
```

PS: arguably, a better solution would be to add these single quotes directly when defining source, target and filename.